# Calculate minimum distance between a point and a polygon in geopandas

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, points

I am trying to compute the minimum distance between a set of points and a set of polygons.

My code looks like this:

```
polys = sf.geometry.tolist()
cities = sf.CITY_LABEL.tolist()
min_dist = np.empty(len(points))
min_city = ['NA'] * len(points)
min_coord = ['NA'] * len(points)
inside = ['NA'] * len(points)
for i, point in enumerate(points):
        aux = sf.boundary.distance(point).tolist()
        idx = aux.index(min(aux))
        min_dist[i] = aux[idx]
        min_city[i] = cities[idx]
        min_coord[i] = polys[idx].boundary.interpolate(polys[idx].boundary.project(point)).wkt
        inside[i] = polys[idx].contains(point)
```

where the variable points contain the points and the variable sf is my shapefile with polygons.

I then save to a file the min distance in degrees, km (deg*111), closest polygon name (a city), the closest polygon point, and whether the point is inside the polygon. So, I have something like this:

[image]

But the minimum distance I computed (column D)  is larger than the distance between the point (column A) and the polygon closest point (column F).

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Why is the distance function returning a different distance than the distance between column A and F?

(I also replicated the code in R, and indeed the minimum distance I get is the one computed between column A and F of the file above, not the one in column D)

Comment: I think the problem is the crs, both shapefile and points are in lat lon form, i.e., epsg:4326 but the distance function is not using the haversine distance formula. I tried to use to_crs() to project the points and polygons to a different crs following this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279109/calculate-distance-between-a-coordinate-and-a-county-in-geopandas, but I still get the wrong distance. Any idea which crs should I use for Los Angeles County?

Comment: create a workable example with hard-coded geometries